Godot - Text stick the a smooth camera
I have just a player that moves and a child camera that follows it with a smooth effect. The problem is that when i put a label on the screen, as a camera's child, it's not stick the camera due to the smoothing effect. How can I do that please ?
I am a debutant, so i tried just to remove the smoothing effect and it works. But I want to keep it.

Instead of adding the label as a child of the camera try adding it to a CanvasLayer as such

This way the label will always appear on screen in-game, here are some additional references:
How to fix a label to a Camera2D, so that it stays on screen?
Building a UI in Godot - Godot Fundamentals
